# Document scanner mobile SDK open source

Tags: android, ios, mobile, sdk

I'm searching for a document scanner SDK for mobile (iOS and Android) that is capable of detecting the edges of a document and then auto-crop it. I know a few licensed SDKs like Scanbot, but is there any open source option?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this blog post](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/09/01/build-kick-ass-mobile-document-scanner-just-5-minutes/) which shows you how to "Build a Kick-Ass Mobile Document Scanner in Just 5 Minutes".

The tool chain being python and OpenCV.

- Detect Document Edges
- Rotate and correct perspective
- Crop
- All Free, Gratis & Open Source.

Comment: Thanks, I had that already, but that won't run on mobile. We have to create the app an translate the Python code to Java/Swift and find similar libraries. Using that code as a backend service isn't an option. Anyway, it doesn't look easy.

Comment: @Rafael OpenCV runs on mobile and for your own use there are python environments available on mobiles - a good possibility is Kivy - https://kivy.org/#home

Comment: I understand. But I already have the two mobile apps, for the two platforms. I'm just adding functionality and Kivy isn't something very popular. If that same code was implemented in Java + OpenCV, then ok. I will probably invest on that and code that solution in Java/Kotlin and Swift.

Answer (score 0):

The answer in this link would work for your use case as well and is used in a Xamarin application: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60828712/crop-image-with-multiple-x-and-y-points-c-sharp/64861791#64861791

```
private RasterImage DetectAndDeskew(RasterImage image)
{
   DetectDocumentCommand detectDocumentCommand = new DetectDocumentCommand();
   detectDocumentCommand.Run(image);

   if (detectDocumentCommand.DocumentArea == null)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("No document detected");
      return null;
   }

   KeyStoneCommand command = new KeyStoneCommand(detectDocumentCommand.DocumentArea);
   command.Run(image);

   image = command.TransformedImage;
   return image;
}
```